# WordPress authentication using email and confirmation link

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I'm trying to change behavior of Wordpress authentication. I have website dedicated for members of my company and I want only them to access it without having to manage lots of different user accounts, validating them etc.

My idea for that is to hide website for not logged in users and show them login form, there, only show email field (done that pretty nice, just created custom page with copy of wp-login.php and made redirection for non logged in viewers, I thought it could be the best way to fully customize login page).

Now I have to change how authentication functions will be behaving, but have totally no idea how to start it, as far as I know, I would have to make lots of different filters for many functions. I have total blackout, can't

Here is the process of registration/login:

- **(done)** User enters the page, if not logged, he will see login form with only email field and submit button
- he will enter his email and hit submit (here I have to get rid of "no password" error message)
- if email is in domain allowed (Array of allowed domains will be provided from options), user will get an email with link to follow to proceed
- after clicking the link user enters the page and is authenticated with "remember me" settings without the need of setting any password etc (and before that, if there is no user witch such email, WP will create one with username containing characters before @ and random strong password)

Because there are so many changes to whole authentication system, I can't wrap my head around it.  Where do I start with modifying required fields? Which hooks should I use?

PS: I don't want to create new authentication system, I need to rely on modifying WP functions.

---

## Got it working! Partial solution below

Already got it working.
I ended up with creating a copy of wp-login page and redirecting all not signed in users to it, page is under /start/.
and page-start.php in my theme is basically copy of wp-login with few tweaks (can't remember all tbh).

I'm not mentioning login form modification and style changes, only scripts.

### page-start.php (copy of wp-login.php)

So first of all, redirect already logged in users to root (at the start of the file):

```
session_start();
if(is_user_logged_in()) {

        wp_redirect( '/' );
        exit;
}
```

next, I've changed part of the code to handle secret login string, if it matches and haven't yet expired (important), it'll login new user.

```
    if(isset($_GET['key'])) {
        $_SESSION['let_me_in_key'] = $_GET['key'];
        session_write_close();
        wp_redirect(home_url('/start/')); 
        exit();
    }
    if(isset($_SESSION['let_me_in_key'])) {
        global $wpdb;
        $let_me_in_key = $_SESSION['let_me_in_key'];
        $_SESSION['let_me_in_key'] = NULL;
        unset($_SESSION['let_me_in_key']);
        $sha = $let_me_in_key;
        $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE user_activation_key LIKE '%{$sha}'",ARRAY_A);
        if (!isset($res[0])) {
            $errors ->add('invalid_key', 'Nieprawidłowy klucz aktywacyjny, zaloguj się ponownie aby otrzymać nowy klucz w wiadomości email.');
        } else {
            $db_key = explode(':',($res[0]['user_activation_key']));
            $minutes = (time()-$db_key[0]);
            if($minutes > 60*60) {
                $errors ->add('expired_key', 'Klucz aktywacyjny wygasł, zaloguj się ponownie aby otrzymać nowy klucz w wiadomości email.');
            } else {
                $user = get_userdata($res[0]['ID']);
                $wpdb->query("UPDATE {$wpdb->users} SET user_activation_key = '' WHERE ID = {$user->ID}");
                clean_user_cache($user->ID);
                wp_clear_auth_cookie();
                wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
                wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true, true);
                update_user_caches($user);
                wp_redirect(home_url());

            }
        }
    }
```

This was added just after this part:

```
if ( $interim_login ) {
        if ( ! $errors->get_error_code() )
            $errors->add( 'expired', __( 'Your session has expired. Please log in to continue where you left off.' ), 'message' );
    } else {
```

### functions.php

Now I've added function to handle custom logins.
First it will remove `wp_authenticate_username_password`, then it'll add it's own auth function
It will check if email is valid, then if it's one of the allowed domains (I'm using ACF, so my custom data is accessed by `get_field()`).
If all that is true, script will generate password with `wp_generate_password` (it doesn't matter what password will be, because users won't ever have to use it, but it's better to create something safer than 123qwe :D) and will create user stripping `@` and leaving only alphanumeric characters from the domain part (I'm not stripping any special characters from part before `@`, but you can).

```
remove_filter('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
add_filter('authenticate', function($user, $email, $password){
        $email = strtolower($_POST['log']);
        $allowed_domains = array_map('trim',array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, get_field('domeny','options'))));
        $domain = explode("@", $email);
        if($_POST['log']) {
            if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){ //Invalid Email
                $error = new WP_Error();
                $error->add('invalid_username', 'Błędny adres email.');
                return $error;
            }
            else if(!in_array($domain[1],$allowed_domains)){ //Invalid Email
                $error = new WP_Error();
                $error->add('invalid_username', 'Niedozwolony adres email. Czy na pewno używasz adresu służbowego?');
                return $error;
            }
        } else return $user;
        //Check if user exists in WordPress database
        $user = get_user_by('email', $email);
            if(!$user){ 
                $pass = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );
                $user_id = wp_create_user( $domain[0].preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]+/", "",$domain[1]), $pass, $email );
                wp_update_user( array( 'ID' => $user_id, 'display_name' => $email ) );
                $user = get_userdata($user_id);
            } else {
                $user_id = $user->ID;
            }

            if(send_activation_link($email,$user_id)) {
                $error = new WP_Error();
                $error->add('confirm', 'Na podany email został wysłany link z potwierdzeniem logowania. Kliknij w link z wiadomości aby przejść dalej.', 'message');
            }
                return $error;
}, 20, 3);
```

I also had to change `wp_authenticate` to get the username:

```
add_action( 'wp_authenticate', 'email_address_login' );
function email_address_login( &$username, &$password )
{
    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $username );

    if( !empty( $user->user_login ) )
    {
        $username = $user->user_login;
    }
}
```

In addition to that, i had to create a function to generate secret key and will send activation link:

```
function send_activation_link($email,$user_id){

add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

    global $wpdb, $wp_hasher;
    $salt = wp_generate_password(20,false); // 20 character "random" string
    $sha = sha1($salt . $email . uniqid(time(), true));
    //$a_z = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $key_saved = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->users, array( 'user_activation_key' => time().':'.$sha ), array( 'ID' => $user_id ) );
    if ( false === $key_saved ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'no_password_key_update', __( 'Could not save password reset key to database.' ) );
    }
    /* send mail here */

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- he will enter his email and hit submit (here I have to get rid of "no
  password" error message)
- if email is in domain allowed (array of allowed domains will be
  provided from options), user will get an email with link to follow to
  proceed

These 2 should be combined - if email in array exist, then use [`wp_insert_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) with an auto-generated password.

- after clicking the link user enters the page and is authenticated
  with "remember me" settings without the need of setting any password
  etc (and before that, if there is no user with such email, WP will
  create one with username containing characters before @ and random
  strong password)

This could be some nonce (see [`wp_nonce_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field)) field which authenticates on return.

It's a long winded question so it's not really a 'one answer' thing - but you would be better suited setting up your own form and using Ajax or something similar.

Comment: Thank you, I got it working already, I'll update original post with what I came up with.
Haven't used `wp_nonce_field` tho, maybe my solution could be modified to use this as a better solution.